# Google map iframe is not working on only IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using iframe code from google map. which is working fine on all the browsers except ie9. Only ie9 is not showing iframe.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3351.1599679719566!2d-96.937731!3d32.8674867!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x864e82bee29a3319%3A0xbe0edd6e043a1a73!2sOmni+Mandalay+Hotel+at+Las+Colinas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1441204417651" width="515" height="403" frameborder="0" style="border:0; float:left" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3351.1599679719566!2d-96.937731!3d32.8674867!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x864e82bee29a3319%3A0xbe0edd6e043a1a73!2sOmni+Mandalay+Hotel+at+Las+Colinas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1441204417651 
event-summary-3f28c902b74a427098a02a241d6e709c.aspx
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3351.1599679719566!2d-96.937731!3d32.8674867!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x864e82bee29a3319%3A0xbe0edd6e043a1a73!2sOmni+Mandalay+Hotel+at+Las+Colinas!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1441204417651 
event-summary-3f28c902b74a427098a02a241d6e709c.aspx
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference 
init_embed.js, line 8 character 332
SCRIPT5009: 'initEmbed' is undefined 
embed, line 14 character 7
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference 
init_embed.js, line 8 character 332
SCRIPT5009: 'initEmbed' is undefined 
embed, line 14 character 7
```

Comment: Show the complete HTML code?

Comment: This is the only code I have in my html page. I am editing the whole code. please check now.

Comment: add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  below <meta charset="utf-8">. that meta tag will force IE9 to use its rendering engine

Comment: I have no excess to html page. :(

Comment: what does the browser show,Is there any error message in console?I emulated for IE9 but it renders perfectly.Fiddle here (try in ie9 )https://jsfiddle.net/njrekv4u/

Comment: Comments Updated with the console . Please check above